# Hot to get id and name from dropdown in angular 4?

Tags: angular, dropdown

In angular 4 
.ts i want to use both accounts.Id and accounts.Name from dropdown. can it be possible?

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedName" class="form-control" (change)="SearchLedgerTransaction($event.target.value)">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option *ngFor="let accounts of accountledger" [value]="accounts.Id && accounts.Name">
          {{accounts.Name}}
      </option>
  </select>
  <br />
  {{selectedName}} Account Ledger View
```

Comment: Try [ngValue]="accounts"

Comment: [value]="accounts.Id" is used to get data from database and i want [value]="accounts.Name" to show selected drop down name value from it.

Comment: using [ngValue] you would get selected object

Comment: You can set Id for value. in the function in `.ts` you can filter it from the array.

Comment: I will try and let you know if it works! Thankx for help.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cqtwra but i need name instead id and i want to use id for other purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use something like..

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedName" class="form-control" (change)="SearchLedgerTransaction($event.target.value)">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option *ngFor="let accounts of accountledger" [value]="accounts">
        {{accounts.Name}}
    </option>
</select>
<br />
{{selectedName.Id}}{{selectedName.Name}} Account Ledger View
```

Comment: Cannot read property 'Id' of undefined or  Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined

Comment: you are getting error after selecting value from dropdown?

Comment: selecting value from dropdown is perfect but i want to get selected name into {{name}} by using ngModel from above select option list.but i have used Id already and i want name. Any ideas ?

Comment: can you share data of `accountledger`? will create and share working example for you

Comment: export class Account{
    Id: number;
    Name: string;}

Comment: <div class="col-md-4" style="float: left; margin-bottom: 10px;">
        <select [(ngModel)]="selectedName" class="form-control" (change)="SearchLedgerTransaction($event.target.value)">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option *ngFor="let accounts of accountledger" [value]="{accounts.Id, accounts.Name}">
                <!--[value]="accounts.Id"-->
                {{accounts.Name}}
            </option>
        </select>
        <br />
        {{selectedName}} Account Ledger View
    </div>

Comment: i hope you can get help from it

Comment: let me apply and find out and tell you what i got in result. Thankx for it.

Comment: Not helped, i got nothing just empty value. <option *ngFor="let accounts of accountledger" [value]="accounts.Id">
                {{accounts.Name}}
            </option> and i want this accounts.Name in the form of {{selectedName}}. don't get it man.

Comment: friend use ngValue not value write code something like...`<option *ngFor="let accounts of accountledger" [ngValue]="accounts.Id"> {{accounts.Name}} </option>`

Comment: check my shared demo my .ts file and html file closely

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cqtwra but i need name instead id and i want to use id for other purpose.

Comment: i done it you can check it on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a41y5y

Comment: At last thank you so much. this function helps me. solved my issue. you are great.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a long list of **accountledger** and want to fetch its id and name only, you can try this method:

```
    <option *ngFor="let accounts of accountledger" 
            [ngValue]="{id: accounts.Id, name: accounts.Name}">  // Use ngValue for multi-select control. Setup the object value you want to assign to the 'selectedName' model
        {{accounts.Name}}
    </option>
```

Then, your **selectedName** model value will become, example: **{ id: 1, name: 'Kristy' }**

Had created a [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-select-multi) for your reference.

---

**UPDATE**

**1.) On your select, you can specify [ngModel] and (ngModelChange) separately.**

```
<select [ngModel]="selectedName" 
        (ngModelChange)="onSelectName($event)"   // Call onSelectName function if select is actively changed
        class="form-control" >

    <option value=""></option>

    <option *ngFor="let accounts of accountledger" 
            [ngValue]="{ id: accounts.Id, name: accounts.Name }">  // Pass Id and Name 
         {{accounts.Name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

**On your Component - Destructure the parameter as the current event value is the passed { id: accounts.Id, name: accounts.Name } from select box [ngValue]**

```
onSelectName({id, name}): void {
   this.selectedName = name;         // Not Recommended; With this, you can now reset the selectedName value to just the name value

   this.name = name;                 // Create new variable to store the name, if you will reassign the selectedName model value which holds ID and Name based on the template [ngValue], it will not reflect the updated data if you reassign it to just name. I suggest you create new one that acts as your official model name to store the selected name. 

   console.log(id);                  // and fetch its ID as well, depends on how you want to use this.
}
```

Comment: Then selected value will be a string `"[object Object]"`

Comment: That looks better:)

Comment: I will try and let you know if it help.  Thankx.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cqtwra but i need name instead id and i want to use id for other purpose.

Comment: @LincolnMandal had update my comment and also forked your repo as well. Hope this helps you with your concern :)  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rvzvsl